# TS lint firing errors when creating logic for passing data to a previous screen on react navigation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, tslint

Below is a code snippet taken from the `react-navigation` documentation on how to pass data to a previous screen.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (route.params?.post) {
      // Post updated, do something with `route.params.post`
      // For example, send the post to the server
       console.log(route.params.post);
    }
  }, [route.params?.post]);
```

Everything works fine however I am getting the following error.

```
Property 'post' does not exist on type 'object'.
```

How do I remove this error ?

Comment: why don't you call when change in router.param change. [router.params]

Comment: I could do that too but it doesn't fix the error since I'm using an if condition

Comment: try this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/ or assign router.params to const like const params:any = route.params then if(params?.post){}